# How can I find all R packages that include graphics functions?

Tags: graphics, r, manual

I always have difficulty in finding all available alternative ways to produce a specific graph, either one that I have already decided to use (looking for different variations) or one that I have not yet thought of.

The [R Graphical Manual](http://bm2.genes.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/index.php?clear=all) site provides a complete list of samples of R's graphics functions, however it's easier for me to search providing a package name (how else -for example- can I get a resultset including `superbarplot` function, when I want to look for barplots?. Let alone that the superbarplot graph does not appear in the results even if I try searching for it's package: `UsingR`)

The [R-SAS-SPSS Add-on Module Comparison](http://sites.google.com/site/r4statistics/add-on-modules) - and especially on topic `Graphics, Static` in the table provided - gave me the idea that it would be nice to have a place where all relevant packages are listed by topic.

Do you have any idea about something like that?

Answer (score 4):

If you're interested in learning about all the possible graphics you can make, you should learn about the grammar of graphics, and (my) implementation of it in R: `ggplot2`.

Comment: :) I agree to a point and I assure you that I have put much effort trying to learn it. However some times I prefer being able to have a choise between several different solutions instead o making one up.

Answer (score 3):

Your question, or the general pattern anyway, was clearly a primary use case for the design of the **sos package**.

sos actually goes one step further that your question requires by identifying particular functions with packages; in addition, it ranks the results by relevance (by default, you can change the default behavior via the "sortby" parameter, e.g., sortby="Date")

Here's how it works:

most of this package's functionality is exposed via the "**findFn**" command

for instance, if you want *a list of all functions and the parent package related to **scatter plots***:

```
findFn("scatter plot", maxPages=2, sortby="TotalScore")
```

This returns a dataframe formatted as HTML table and delivered in your default browser (if you don't want it to pop-up immediately, then just bind the function call to a variable and then call the variable when you're ready)

The right-most column of the dataframe/HTML page is "Description and Link". Clicking an entry in that column opens another tab in your browser (according to the user-set preferences set in your browser) with the complete R help page for that function.

The results from the function call above show, for instance, that the functions for plotting data in a 'scatter plot' format are found in the following packages:

- ade4 (function: scatter)
- IDPmisc (functions: ipairs, iplots)
- GGally (function: ggally_points)
- PerformanceAnalytics (function:
  chart.Scatter)
- mclust (function: clPairs)

Another example:

```
findFn("boxplot", maxPages=2, sortby="TotalScore")
```

identifies these (among others) packages/functions for plotting boxplots:

- sfsmisc (function: boxplot.matrix)
- aplpack (function: boxplot2D)
- NADA (function: boxplot-methods)
- StatDA (function: rg.boxplot)
- plotrix (function: gap.boxplot)
- gplots (function: boxplot.n)
- multcompView (function:
  multcompBoxplot)
- oligo (function: boxplot)

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the [R Graph Gallery](http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/) ?

Other than that, you may have to index all the source code of CRAN packages to search efficiently...

Comment: Yes, R Graph Gallery is a site that I use very often (I also use this one http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Created_with_R ). I didn't understand how code indexing is done. Could you explain it?

Comment: You would have to download all sources, unpack them, grep for instances of plot(), xyplot(), ... and index that for your convenience.  I was trying to say that I doubt such a meta-index exists.  That is, outside of the existing R-search engines like Rseek.org etc.

Answer (score 1):

these are good memory-joggers.  I second the ggplot2 recommend, also recommend looking thru CRAN views:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/

http://cran.fhcrc.org/web/views/Graphics.html

(this mirror seems faster in west coast US)

---

http://dataspora.com/archive/2009/seminar/Survey_of_R_Graphics_by_Driscoll_Dataspora_Jun2009.pdf

---

http://zoonek2.free.fr/UNIX/48_R/04.html

(possibly world's longest webpage)

http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/120/lectures.html

Ihaka's lectures notes